# How to prevent event bubbling in Angular 9 with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, event-bubbling

I have a navbar component in my Angular 9 code, where the user see a countdown timer with their session time. It's count down in every seconds.

My component looks like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  timer: any;
  countdownTimer = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startTimer();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.stopTimer();
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.countdownTimer = this.milisecondsToTime(3600000);
    }, 1000);
  }

  milisecondsToTime(duration: number): string {
    const seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60);
    const minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    const hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

    const hoursString = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
    const minutesString = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    const secondsString = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    return hoursString + ':' + minutesString + ':' + secondsString;
  }

  stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
```

In the nav.component.html:

```html
      <div>
        Session: {{ countdownTimer }}
      </div>
```

With this code in every second happening an event bubbling and in the all of my code run functions over and over again. The codebase is getting big enough and this event bubbling slowing down all of the software.

Is there a better way or a best practice to show a countdown timer and don't flood the Angular with event in every seconds?

Answer (score 1):

With Angular 9 you can set a new property`ngZoneEventCoalescing` to prevent event bubbling. You need to add it within `bootstrapModule` method.

Example

```
  platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule, { ngZoneEventCoalescing: true })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

You can read more about this [here](https://netbasal.com/reduce-change-detection-cycles-with-event-coalescing-in-angular-c4037199859f)

Answer (score 0):

I use your code above it does not start a countdown, i not sure what is the 3600000 value stand for, i assume is a duration of countdown, maybe? i created a example not sure it is the solution that you looking for.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zb7l6w

Comment: 3600000 represent the session time in miliseconds, from where the countdown timer start counting down

Comment: mean my assumption is correct, if you use the way i created in the code snippet is still happen the issue of event bubbling ?